# Bootstrap Modal and JQuery Change Event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

in my page script I put the following script for when the modal is loaded:

```
$("#ClientRealEstate_Status").live("change", function () {
    CheckRealEstateStatus();
});

function CheckRealEstateStatus() {
    var ddl = $("#ClientRealEstate_Status");
    alert(ddl.val());
    if ($(ddl).val() == "Mortgage") {
        $(".outstanding").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".outstanding").hide();
    }
}
```

Even though the dropdown is populated with a selected value, the alert is always blank and never performs the hide and show of the div that I need shown/hidden. Not sure what I'm overlooking here.

UPDATE for fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/janessaallen/x4nj9rbr/

Comment: try with ddl=$('#ClientRealEstate_Status :selected').text();

Comment: tried that and was still blank. Good one, though.

Comment: @jallen what do u mean by loading modal?, can you create a fiddle to explain your issue ?

Comment: @jallen let's try changing the "live" with "change". Also, as suren recommends, put your code in a fiddle. Which version of jquery you're using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/janessaallen/x4nj9rbr/

Comment: Your "live" code is inside $(document).ready?           $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ClientRealEstate_Status").on("change", function () {
                CheckRealEstateStatus();
            });
        })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this meaby works,

just changed the "show" for "modal" and add the moda(hide) for close it...

```
function CheckRealEstateStatus() {
    var ddl = $("#ClientRealEstate_Status");
    alert(ddl.val());
    if ($(ddl).val() == "Mortgage") {
        $(".outstanding").modal();
    }
    else {
        $(".outstanding").modal('hide');
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP states that the alert always return blank values. The problem resides in $("#ClientRealEstate_Status").val();

Comment: I'm sorry, not following. What do you mean by OP?

Comment: @jallen OP: Original Post.

Comment: I do think the problem resides in that dropdown somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/x4nj9rbr/1/

Use **on** instead of **live**.

```
 $("#ClientRealEstate_Status").on("change", function () {
         CheckRealEstateStatus();
     });

function CheckRealEstateStatus() {
    var ddl = $("#ClientRealEstate_Status");
    alert(ddl.val());
    if ($(ddl).val() == "Mortgage") {
        $(".outstanding").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".outstanding").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out that the issue is when the dropdown has a prepopulated value in it from the model being passed. Then it doesn't recognize the value that's being selected. So it's almost like my original question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Visual Studio on this way, and it worked:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClientRealEstate_Status").on("change", function () {
            CheckRealEstateStatus();
        });
    })

    function CheckRealEstateStatus() {
        var ddl = $("#ClientRealEstate_Status");
        alert(ddl.val());
        console.log(ddl.val());
        if ($(ddl).val() == "Mortgage") {
            $(".outstanding").show();
        }
        else {
            $(".outstanding").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```